# Tratar erros de SOAP

Tags: genexus, soap

Estou a consumir um método de webservice via ExternalObject (importado do "WSDL Import").

Na prática, a invocação leva o Id como parâmetro e o serviço retorna o nome do arquivo correspondente:

```
&NomeArquivo = getDocumentName(&DocumentId)
```

O que acontece é que, quando o &DocumentId não existe, a aplicação devolve um erro para a janela de output:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.SOAP Fault: Error in server execution.
>   Message: pt.xxx.ContentServerException: DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND: Document not found: 5722 Detail: xxxx
>   at GeneXus.Programs.SdtContentServicesV2.getdocumentfile(Int32 gxTp_documentId, String gxTp_revisionName)
>   at GeneXus.Programs.acarregatodosnomeficheiro.executePrivate()
>   at GeneXus.Programs.acarregatodosnomeficheiro.Main(String[] args)
>   Execution Failed**

Eu queria (1) colocar esse erro numa tabela e (2) que a execução não fosse interrompida.
Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a propiedade CancelOnError.
Esta propriedade é usada para indicar como os erros serão tratados ao chamar um objeto GeneXus através de SOAP e ao invocar um Web Service importado com GeneXus WSDL Inspector.

Obter mais informações em http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?7020

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa propriedade. Resolveu na perfeição. Muito obrigado.